# Racking my brain trying to replace a substring in a formula without replacing a slightly larger substring?

Tags: excel, vba, replace, substitution

To put it simply, I have a cell with the formula

```
=IF(A4="Name", IFERROR(J4*(I4-AI4), 0), "")
```

I am trying to replace "I4" with say "BH4" without "AI4" also being turned into "ABH4".  But it cannot be assumed that the formula will always follow this pattern (so not really an option to just find and replace the 1st occurrence of the string or something like that

I've looked into both the Replace and Substitute function but they don't seem to handle wildcards.
I also tried using the Range.Replace method which I think is suppose to be able to handle wildcards, but I was unable to really get it to work.  But even then if I'm not really sure what wildcard setup would work

Comment: replace `(I4` with `(BH4`?

Comment: @ScottCraner lol this is actually what I ended up having to do just to get the macro to be able to work but also checking for other operators and punctuation like " ", "-", "*", and "," but I was hoping to find a more elegant solution to the situation

Answer (score 2):

Say the formula is in cell **B9**.

This will only change the **first** occurrence of the substring:

```
Sub FixFormula()
    With Range("B9")
        .Formula = Application.Substitute(.Formula, "I4", "BH4", 1)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, my only problem is I hoped to use the same general principle in other columns which will have formulas in different formats and I can't assume that the string that needs to be replaced will only need to be replaced once or that it will be the left most occurrence

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to use a regex something like this:

```
Sub regex()

    Set myRegExp = New RegExp
    myRegExp.Pattern = "([^a-zA-Z])I4([^a-zA-Z])"
    
    With Range("A1")
        .Formula = myRegExp.Replace(.Formula, "$1AB4$2")
    End With

End Sub
```

Note that you have to go to Tools|References first in the VBA screen and enable Microsoft VBScript regular expressions 5.5.

Comment: Thank you this looks to be something along the lines of what I was hoping to be able to do, I will look into it.